# Nonsmooth behavior of numerical integral in R (function `integrate`)

Tags: r, integral, numerical-integration

I am doing numerical integration in R with the function `integrate`. I am integrating a function `fun1` and have discovered some nonsmooth behavior. Changing the integral's lower bound slightly produces a big jump in the calculated value of the integral; compare `aaa` and `ccc` below. `aaa` is approximately correct, as can be verified using online numerical integral calculators. However, `ccc` is far from the truth.

For illustrative purposes, I split the integration interval into two and sum the two parts. The result is very different from integrating over a single interval. This should not be the case, as algebraically the two are equal.

```
fun1 <- function(x, d){
 min( 0, -(exp(x)-0.1*abs(exp(x)-d)-0.05*(exp(x)-d))^(-1) ) * dnorm(x=x,mean=0,sd=0.05)
}
aaa <- integrate(f=fun1, d=0.8932789, lower=-3.159041, upper=40       )$value; aaa
bbb <- integrate(f=fun1, d=0.8932789, lower=-3.159041, upper=-3.157379)$value; bbb
ccc <- integrate(f=fun1, d=0.8932789, lower=-3.157379, upper=40       )$value; ccc
aaa-(bbb+ccc) # This should be (but is not) close to zero because algebraically, aaa-(bbb+ccc)=0
```

**Questions:** Why is this happening? How do I fix this? I.e. how do I get a correct value for `ccc`?

Comment: Plot your function in the desired interval. Next, read the `Note` section of `?integrate`: `Like all numerical integration routines, these evaluate the
     function on a finite set of points.  If the function is
     approximately constant (in particular, zero) over nearly all its
     range it is possible that the result and error estimate may be
     seriously wrong`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665689/integrate-a-very-peaked-function-in-r ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122505/integrate-gives-totally-wrong-number ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023899/integrate-in-r-gives-terribly-wrong-answer?rq=1

Comment: Function `cubature::hcubature` (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122769/8245406) to the question in @BenBolker [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617774/nonsmooth-behavior-of-numerical-integral-in-r-function-integrate#comment112497359_63617774)) gives `aaa-(bbb+ccc)` equal to `[1] 1.994734e-07`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, thank you! Currently it looks like `hcubature` is doing better than `integrate`. I have tried out quite a bit of tuning tricks to make `integrate` work properly, but `hcubature` gets a more accurate answer with way less programming effort. The only drawback for now is that it is about 10x slower than `integrate` for my data.